# How do I make changes in winetricks permanent?

Tags: osx, winetricks

I downloaded a game powered by wineskin X11, it requires videomemory of at least 1GB

winetricks works great, but each time I will have to open the dialog, modify it and run the game.

[image: winetricks]

Any ideas? I need to make this change permanent